# express fileupload package problem with the path

Tags: node.js, image, express, upload, express-fileupload

I'm encountering a problem when I want to upload a file to 'public' folder. This problem occurs when I don't use `'./'`. if I use `'../'` or `'/'` files do not upload to the public folder.

```
**controllers.js**
files.forEach(file => {
        file.mv('../public/' + file.name, err => {
            if (err) {
                log({ err });
                return res.redirect('/')
            }

            log('file uploaded');

        })
    })
```

Error:  `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\public\image4.jpg'`

And also this error: `Express-file-upload: Request is not eligible for file upload!`

This happens when I'm inside `controllers/controllers.js`. If I write this code inside `app.js`, I do not face any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file.mv()` method works relative to the `cwd` current working directory path.

To let it work, you need to write like:

```
const path = require('path')

const fileName = path.join(__dirname, '../public/', file.name)

file.mv(fileName)
```

By doing so, the path will be relative to the `controller.js` file (and not relative to the `cwd`)